# In ASP.NET MVC, send server function's execution status to the client

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following button which downloads a very large PDF by calling the `DownloadPdf()` function within `DownloadController`.

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg float-right" style="background-color:dodgerblue" title="Download as PDF" href="@Url.Action("DownloadPdf", "Download", new { id = Model.Id })" )">
    <span data-feather="download" style="color:white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

The issue is that the `DownloadPdf()` method takes a very long time because it pulls lots of small pieces from various databases and put them together into one PDF. It takes a couple of seconds to gather the data, and it also takes some time to convert the document to PDF using `PdfSharp`.

**My question is: Since `DownloadPdf()` is a server-side method, is it possible for the client UI to display a status update of the progress of the `DownloadPdf()` method?** For example, it would be great if `DownloadPdf()` could set some variable with a string value "Gathering Data 1 of 10" or "Creating PDF", send that variable's value to the client, and display that to the user.

Comment: Take a look at SignalR - this is ideal for updating the client with your progress.

Comment: It's a non-trivial thing, but it's possible.  Using something like SignalR to maintain the websocket communication between the server and the client would likely be the way to go.  There are some examples for reporting the statuses of multi-step processed back to a client (such as an ordering/payment process in a shopping system).